# Is there a Closed-form distribution for a Beta-Beta distribution?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, beta-distribution

Let's say I have a beta distribution parametrized with $\mu, \phi$ such that given a random variable $X$
$$X\sim Beta(\mu,\phi),\quad \mu =\frac{a}{a+b}, \quad \phi = a+b$$

Now let a and b be independent gamma distributions such that
$$a\sim Gamma(\alpha, 1),\quad b\sim Gamma(\beta,1)$$

Thus it follows from change of variables and gamma sums that
$$\mu\sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$$
$$\phi\sim Gamma(\alpha+\beta,1)$$

The Probability distribution of $X$ is then
$$f(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{B_x(a,b)G_a(\alpha,1)G_b(\beta,1)}dadb}$$

Where $B_x(\cdot)$ is the beta pdf and $G_x(\cdot)$ is the Gamma PDF.  Is there a closed form solution to this equation? Or do I have to estimate it numerically?

Edit: Re-expressed the model since my original didnt address $a$ and $b$

Comment: How can $\mu$ be a random variable, while $\theta$ is not, if they are both functions of $a$ and $b$? And if $\mu =\frac{a}{a+b}$ is a random variable, then presumably you really want to say that $a$ and $b$ are random variables ... but you do not provide a model for them.

Comment: If $a \sim Gamma(\alpha, 1)$ and $b \sim Gamma(\beta, 1)$ independently of $a$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed, then $\mu \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$. For that reason, $\phi \sim Gamma(\alpha + \beta, 1)$. Using this you can fix your distribution of $X$.

Comment: Fixed original post.  Yes, I didn't really consider a and b before but your specifications makes much more sense.  Given this, is there still a closed-form solution we can derive or do we still have to estimate it numerically?

Comment: If $\mu = \mu(a,b)$ and $\phi = \phi(a,b)$, then it is likely that $\mu$ and $\phi$ are not independent ... in which case you may need to set your integral up in terms of $a$ and $b$ (not $\mu$ and $\phi$).

Comment: I also think your model is far too complicated, if you have any aspirations of getting a closed form solution. Even assuming $a$ and $b$ are iid Uniform(0,1) will be terribly difficult to solve. I suspect you want something much simpler, such as fixing $\phi$, and letting $\mu \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ for starters.

Comment: Wouldn't the same thing arise?  If $\mu$ is said to be uniformly distributed, doesn't that imply that a and b are random variables as well?  Sorry if I'm not seeing anything that should be clear.

Comment: No - I meant dropping $a$ and $b$. Fix $\phi$ as a fixed parameter. And let $\mu$ have some simple distribution.

Comment: I see.  Thank you, I will try that.   If you want you can write that as an answer and I'll mark that as answered.

Comment: As a side question, how would one solve for the pdf if mu is standard uniform?  I attempted a few times on paper and couldn't seem to figure it out.